# Should bootstrapping and collecting sample means from a series of binomial distributions result in standard normal?

Tags: binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem, type-i-and-ii-errors, law-of-large-numbers

I’m trying to better understand several statistical concepts (bootstrapping, central limit theorem, and confidence intervals) by applying them to a binomial distribution (you can think of it as a coin flip, for example).

I’ll explain my expectations/sanity checks, and then hopefully someone can tell me why my expectations don’t match the results I’m getting in my simulation in code.

*Procedure:*

1. Given a probability of success (e.g. $p=0.5$), I obtain the results of 1000 bernoulli trials.
2. I do this 1000 times, which means I get 1000 resamples.  From each resample, I compute the sample mean (p=% of positives from the 1000 bernoulli trials), and the sample variance ($n*p*(1-p)$).
3. I can then construct a “bootstrap distribution” which is the distribution of the sample means.
4. construct test statistic for $S_n$, standardized and normalized: $$\frac{S_n - p}{\sigma/\sqrt{1000}}$$, where $p$ is the "true" probability of success.
5. Determine the desired $\alpha$ (type I error rate), and get corresponding $Z$ values:  $Z_{\alpha/2}$ and $Z_{1-\alpha/2}$ (for $\alpha=0.05$ I determined these to be $+/- 1.96$.
6. Determine if the test statistic from step 4) is within the $Z$-values: $Z_{\alpha/2} \le \frac{S_n - p}{\sigma/\sqrt{1000}} \le Z_{1-\alpha/2}$
7. If so, then we correctly accept the null hypothesis that the probability of success is $p$.  If not, then we reject the null hypothesis, and call it a type I error.
8. Fix $p$ (true probability of success), and $\alpha$ (type I error rate), and repeat steps 1) through 7) 1000 times, and we would expect 50 type I errors.

*Expectation (with justification):*

1. I expect the bootstrap distribution to have the following:

   a. mean ($S_n$) = mean of sample means of the resamples (by the law of large numbers).

   b. variance (($\sigma^2)/1000$) = mean of sample variances (by the law of large numbers) divided by 1000 (number of resamples).

   c. Normally distributed (by central limit theorem, see below)
2. I expect the central limit theorem to apply here because (see “classic CLT” described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)):
   a. The sample means are i.i.d
3. If the two expectations above are true, then I would expect 95% of the sample means to fall within the confidence interval for the normal distribution parameterized by $S_n$ and $\sigma^2/1000$
4. I expect the percentage of type I errors to be 5% (50 out of 1000).

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import stats

    def run_test(error_count):
        n=1000 # number of bernoulli trials. one set of bernoulli trials is a resample
        size=1000  # number of resamples
        theta=0.5
        sample_means = []
        sample_variances = []

        # 1) 
        bootstrap_resamples = np.random.binomial(n, theta, size)

        # 2)
        for resample in bootstrap_resamples:
            sample_mean = resample/float(n)
            sample_variance = float(n)*sample_mean*(1-sample_mean)
            sample_means.append(sample_mean)
            sample_variances.append(sample_variance)

        # 3)
        # sample_means (see above) 

        # 4) 
        S_n = np.mean(sample_means)
        sigma_squared = np.mean(sample_variances)
        sigma = np.sqrt(sigma_squared)
        test_statistic  = (S_n - theta)/(sigma/np.sqrt(1000))

        # 5) 
        alpha=0.05
        if not stats.norm.ppf(alpha/2.0) <  test_statistic < stats.norm.ppf(1-(alpha/2.0)):
            error_count +=1
        return error_count


    error_count = 0
    for i in range(1000):
        error_count = run_test(error_count)

    print error_count
```

The above code consistently returns 0 errors.  In other words, `print error_count` returns `0`, when I would expect it to return approximately 50.

In most cases it might be good to have 0 errors, but I'm trying to validate that the $\alpha$ level influences the number of errors, and I'm not seeing that here.

I have a suspicion that the test statistic is computed incorrectly, but I can't figure out what it is...Do you perhaps see an issue in my computation?

Thank you.

Comment: 1. "*I always thought that the central limit theorem meant that the sample means would be distributed by a standard normal.*" -- this is wrong in several ways at once. It might be worth reading about various forms of the CLT on Wikipedia (but perhaps focus on the classical CLT for simplicity).  2. Posting code without first clearly saying what the code is implementing is problematic because it conflates errors of understanding with errors of implementation. It's much better to resolve your errors of understanding first (by explaining what you're intending to implement), without code.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica, thanks for your feedback. Allow me to edit.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica, I did what you suggested, and I looked at classical CLT from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem.  I hope the question looks much nicer now.  Thanks.

Comment: This looks fine to me--except you do not describe a bootstrap.  It's close to a *parametric* bootstrap, but subtly different.  The parametric bootstrap would be executed by first generating a sample of 1000 iid Bernoulli(0.5) variates and setting $p$ to equal their mean. Then you would resume at step 1 using this $p$ rather than a value of $0.5.$  The point is that in the bootstrap you never know the true mean: you are using the sample estimate as a surrogate.

Comment: Okay, thanks whuber for you feedback.  @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica, what was your hesitation with my approach?  I editted my question to expand upon my procedure – my ultimate goal is to validate the type I error rate, given a true probability of success $p$, and a value for $\alpha$.  It essentially conducts an equivalence test, and then repeats all of the steps many times, and tallies up the number of errors, and uses that for approximating the type I error.

Comment: My initial hesitation was simply trying to guess what you were really doing (rather than trying to figure out what your code did).

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica I actually understand this much better now - so, thank you! Now I'm going to post the corresponding code below it, and hopefully someone can help me figure out why it is giving me 0 errors consistently.

Comment: Could you explain what "giving me 0 errors" means?  One might interpret that as "giving me zero errors; i.e.,, no errors," which ideally is what you want, right?

Comment: The simulation mixes up bernoulli trials and their sum. sample_mean = resample/float(n) is the sample mean of n bernoulli trials. But sample_variance = float(n)*sample_mean*(1-sample_mean) is the sample variance of the *sum* of 1000 bernoulli trials

Comment: @CloseToC, from what I'm seeing, the line `sample_variance = float(n)*sample_mean*(1-sample_mean) ` is *inside* the `for` loop, so it is computed for *each* set of 1000 bernoulli trials.  So, it computes the empirical variance for each set of 1000 bernoulli trials, and then in end, takes the average of all of the empirical variances, to get an unbiased estimate of the variance for one resample...is there something I'm missing?
whuber I edited the question again - hopefully now it's more clear.

Comment: It is the sample variance of the random variable $\sum_i X_i$, the number of successes. But the sample mean in the simulation is the fraction of successes. This means that test_statistic does not have variance 1 as required. If you set sample_variance = sample_mean*(1-sample_mean) / n the simulation will give you the results you expect but you have an unnecessary loop in the simulation that makes things hard to understand. You average sample averages. But sample_mean, appropriately scaled, is already approximately normally distributed because it involves a sum of 1000 independent rv.

Comment: @CloseToC that worked – thanks!  Okay, I still don’t understand this 100%.  How did you get the variance to be  `sample_variance = sample_mean*(1-sample_mean) / n` ?  Let's say our random variable is the probability of success, $p$, which you seem to be suggesting.  Since the variance of a Bernoulli distribution is $p*(1-p)$, I would have thought we would need `sample_variance = sample_mean*(1-sample_mean) `.  What about a Bernoulli distribution tells you to divide the entire variance by $n$ ?

Comment: Just to make sure I really get this, alternatively let's say our random variable is actually the *number* of successes.  then, we would be trying to find the mean and variance of a binomial distribution.  The variance of a binomial distribution is $n*p*(1-p)$.  In our case $p$ is represented by `(sample_mean/n) `.  So, in the code above we should modify with `sample_mean = resample` and `sample_variance = (n*(sample_mean/n)*(1- (sample_mean/n)))`.  I know that looks complicated, but I’m trying to be explicit.  Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @CloseToC, can you confirm my understanding please?  Thanks.

Comment: And, how did you know to divide by $n$ in the sample variance? There must be something I don't understand here.

Comment: @Hunle I've added an explanation of what's going in your simulation as an answer. The reason it works is probably a bit more complicated than anticipated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first describe with mathematical notation what happens in the simulation (when dividing by n) and then lay out the statistics that would lead one to expect the result.

```
bootstrap_resamples = np.random.binomial(n, theta, size)
```

Generates $S=1000$ binomial random variables, $Y_s$ each consisting of the sum of $N=1000$ Bernoulli trials with success probability $\theta$, $Y_s = \sum_j^{N} X_{s, j}$

```
sample_mean = resample/float(n)
sample_variance = sample_mean*(1-sample_mean) / n
```

Calculates $\hat{\theta}_s = \frac{1}{N} \sum_j^{N} X_{s, j}$ and $\hat{\text{v}}_s = \frac{\hat{\theta_s}(1-\hat{\theta_s})}{N}$

```
  S_n = np.mean(sample_means)
  sigma_squared = np.mean(sample_variances)
  sigma = np.sqrt(sigma_squared)
  test_statistic  = (S_n - theta)/(sigma/np.sqrt(1000))
```

Calculates $\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{S} \sum_s^S \hat{\theta}_s$ and $\hat{\text{v}} = \frac{1}{S} \sum_s^S \hat{\text{v}_s}$ then $\text{stat} = \frac{ \hat{\theta} - \theta}{ \sqrt{ S^{-1} \hat{\text{v}} } }$

```
       if not stats.norm.ppf(alpha/2.0) <  test_statistic < stats.norm.ppf(1-(alpha/2.0)):
        error_count +=1
```

Finally, compute the indicator variable $Q = \text{stat} \not \in (-1.96, 1.96)$

Now, what is the sampling distribution of $Q$? If $\text{stat}$ is approximately standard normal, then it approximately equals $5\%$. This is in fact the case because a central limit theorem applies.

Looking at $\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{S \cdot N} \sum_s \sum_j X_{s,j}$ that is just an average of $S\cdot N$ Bernoulli variables. If we subtract its mean divide by its standard deviation, it will have mean zero and variance 0. It consists of a sum of iid random variables, so will be approximately normal in large samples and be within (-1.96, 1.96) $95\%$ of the time.  We have $E[ \hat{\theta} ] = \theta$ and $Var( \hat{\theta} ) = \text{V} =  \frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{S\cdot N} $.

So $$\frac{ \hat{\theta} - \theta }{ \sqrt{\text{V}}}$$ is approximately standard normal by a CLT. In the simulation, the approximation will be really good because the sum is over a million random variables. If you want to focus only on understanding the CLT, divide by $v$ in the simulation. And you could have just looked at the mean of 1000 bernoulli trials instead of the mean over 1000 means.

However, the denominator of $\text{stat}$ isn't $\sqrt{V}$ and yet the simulation still yields $Q$ at around $5\%$ anyways. Why? Because the denominator of $\text{stat}$ converges in probability to the root of $V$ by a law of large numbers. And there's another theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) that says asymptotically, that's as good as if it it actually was $V$. To see the denominator works out:
The denominator of $\text{stat}$ is the root of $\frac{1}{S \cdot S} \sum_s^S \hat{\text{v}_s} = \frac{1}{S \cdot S} \sum_s^S \frac{\hat{\theta_s}(1-\hat{\theta_s})}{N} = \frac{1}{S \cdot N} \left( \frac{1}{S} \sum_s \hat{\theta_s}  - \frac{1}{S}  \sum_s \hat{\theta_s}^2 \right)$. The quantities inside the brackets will converge to $\theta$ and $\theta^2$ by a law of large numbers, so the denominator will converge to the root of $V$ and Slutsky's theorem kicks in.

Comment: This is extremely helpful.  How did you know to divide by $N$ in the formula for estimating the variance of $S$? I could understand if that were the formula for the variance of a bernoulli distribution.  And I understand that the mean of a Bernoulli distribution is obviously just the probability of success, which in our case is taken to be $\hat \theta_s$, as you have indicated.  But the corresponding variance $v_S$ of a Bernoulli distribution is $v_S = \hat \theta_s ( 1 - \hat \theta_s )$, but you have $v_S = \frac{\hat \theta_s ( 1 - \hat \theta_s )}{N}$.  How did you know to divide by $N$?

Comment: @Hunle: The variance is only needed to scale the statistic so that its variance is $1$ (otherwise, its distribution cannot be compared to a standard normal random variable which has variance 1). The statistic here is a sample mean $\frac{1}{N} \sum_i X_i$, and the variance of a sample mean of uncorrelated random variables is s $\frac{\sigma^2}{N}$

Comment: I see, so in this case, we’re computing the variance of a bernoulli distribution, and then scaling it to fit the standard normal as desired.  The independent random variables are the number of successes from each sample of bernoulli trials (as you denote it, $X_{s,j}$.  The sample mean is obviously $\hat \theta_S$, as you indicated, and since these are means of bernoulli trials, the variance is $\hat \theta_S(1-\hat \theta_S)$.  Then, we shift and scale the distribution of the sample mean by first subtracting the true mean 0.5, and scaling by square root of sample variance, divided by $N$.